# how to display SimpleXMLElement with php

Tags: php, xml

Hi I have never used xml but need to now, so I am trying to quickly learn but struggling with the structure I think. This is just to display the weather at the top of someones website.

I want to display Melbourne weather using this xml link ftp://ftp2.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10753.xml

Basically I am trying get Melbourne forecast for 3 days (what ever just something that works) there is a forecast-period array [0] to [6]

I used this print_r to view the structure:

```
$url = "linkhere";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
```

and tried this just to get something:

```
$url = "linkhere";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$data = (string) $xml->forecast->area[52]->description;
echo $data;
```

Which gave me nothing (expected 'Melbourne'), obviously I need to learn and I am but if someone could help that would be great.

Comment: Does your script produce errors? What does the echo $data output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `description` is an attribute of `<area>`, you need to use

```
$data = (string) $xml->forecast->area[52]['description'];
```

I also wouldn't rely on *Melbourne* being the 52nd area node (though this is really up to the data maintainers). I'd go by its `aac` attribute as this appears to be unique, eg

```
$search = $xml->xpath('forecast/area[@aac="VIC_PT042"]');
if (count($search)) {
    $melbourne = $search[0];
    echo $melbourne['description'];
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks! first useful thing that has echoed all day :)

Comment: @user2829848 I've updated my answer with some more information that you may find useful

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but how would I get down to the forecast-period array I tried this $xml->forecast->area[52]->{forecast-period}[0]['start-time-local'];

Comment: I got it sorry I had no '' around forecast-period

Comment: @user2829848 You simply use `$melbourne->{'forecast-period'}`. Don't forget the quotes around *forecast-period*

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example for you:

```
<?php

$forecastdata = simplexml_load_file('ftp://ftp2.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10753.xml','SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    foreach($forecastdata->forecast->area as $singleregion) {
    $area = $singleregion['description'];
    $weather = $singleregion->{'forecast-period'}->text;
    echo $area.': '.$weather.'<hr />';  
    }

?>
```

You can edit the aforementioned example to extract the tags and attributes you want.

Always remember that a good practice to understand the structure of your XML object is printing out its content using, for instance, `print_r`

In the specific case of the XML you proposed, cities are specified through attributes (*description*). For this reason you have to read also those attributes using ['attribute name'] ([see here for more information](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)).

Notice also that the tag `{'forecast-period'}` is wrapped in curly brackets cause it contains a hyphen, and otherwise it wouldn generate an error.